# Display table margin/padding

Tags: css

I don't know how to have the yellow 50px gap at the top and on the right,
without increasing the size of the container, so the scroll bars do not show up.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cont">
       <div class="left">left</div>
       <div class="right">right</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px 50px 0 0;   
}

.cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333333;
    display: table-row;

}

.left{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #FF0000;
}

.right{
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

Please see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL463/10/

I tried replacing padding with margin, but it doesn't help.

Please can someone explain how can I do this.

Comment: simplest way is to add a background color: http://jsfiddle.net/bL463/11/

Comment: sorry, it was a wrong fiddle link, updated. The color is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL463/12/

The default border-sizing method is `content-box` which excludes the padding and border of an item form the overall dimensions. Using border-box these propertys will be added in this calculations.

Comment: Do you know any good read about this? Some article or yt tut? There is a lot on google but not sure what to read to get the latest/correct info

Comment: Sorry, just a quick one. If I don't want to set box-sizing for everything (*), what is the best place to put it in? Inside wrapper, where 'display:table' is?

Comment: You need it for every element that you want to have a certain width and/or height and you want the size of padding and borders to not change these values. In your example it is enough to set the `.wrapper` to `boder-box` since it have `width:100%;` and some padding. http://jsfiddle.net/bL463/13/

Comment: I am still having some problems, please see http://jsfiddle.net/pQq45/1/ The scrolls should appear inside the left container, but instead the scroll apears on the body. Should I ask a separate question for this?